# How make kendoDatePicker to show special datetime in its dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

I used KendoDatePicker in my ASP.NET MVC to have Persian(Shamsi) calendar in my project and today is 1398/07/23 and as you see in below picture this datepicker has shown excactly the true date for today.
[image]

But something that I need is that when we open its dropdown for the first time then this datepicker must show us a date from 18 years ago(1370/01/01) in the dropdown. Consider that this kind of datetime is Persian(Shamsi) datetime. I have below config in my razor view:

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#BirthDate").kendoDatePicker();
    });
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem? Any help will be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by below jquery code:

```
<script>
    var pastDate = new Date(1991, 2, 21);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#BirthDate").kendoDatePicker({
            value: pastDate,
            min: pastDate
        }).val('').data("kendoDatePicker");
    });
</script>
```